# How to pass a buffer of binary-data to xml?

Tags: c++, xml

**Hi to you all,**

- I have a buffer which contains binary-data (size of more than 1G) ...
- This binary-data are pointed-to by a pointer of "Ipp16s" (Intel data-type for "short") ...
- The pointer is pointing "only" to the first element of the buffer and not to all the buffer (as I was told and checked myself when debugging)) ...
- Eventually, I would like to fit the whole buffer into an xml ...
- I already set-up the xml format and it is working when passing mock values ...
- So, I thought of two solutions:

  1. inserting the single-values one-by-one (using a for-loop) into the
     xml (which is very simple method yet inefficient for so many
     reasons)
  2. encoding (somehow) the buffer (and all its contents) before
     injecting the encoded buffer into the xml (this method sounds
     complicated but more logical)

**My question is: how to encode this buffer (of binary data) into xml ?**

BTW, I am new to c++ and working with Qt-Creator.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally use [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding. I'm sure you could find an implementation already written, or you could write your own if it appeals.

Comment: **thanks for your reply ...**

after I read through base64 encoding, I found this website: (http://cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/51572)

however the implementation is concentrating on passing only string value(s). **I am more concern with passing a pointer to a buffer (that contains binary data)**.

I can't see how to implement that using base64 !!

Comment: base64 encoding is that same whether you're encoding from a string, from a buffer, from a file. Always you are encoding bytes, where you get the bytes from is just a detail. Here's an implementation that encodes from a buffer http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/common/base64.html

Comment: your example is same as mine. that is it: I have to put char values to the variable "s" before passing "s" to the encoder (and I can't pass my buffer because I don't have it, i have only a pointer to it). another thing, the code is passing "s" as an one-length buffer of char, and I want to pass a pointer that only point to the first element in the buffer which contains "short" values. I am really stuck !!

Comment: I think maybe you don't understand pointers. All you need is a pointer to the first element and the length of the buffer. base64 encoding only works for bytes. You need to translate your shorts into bytes. How you do that is a different question. The simplest answer is just to cast the short pointer to a byte pointer, although that may not be the right answer depending on what exactly you are trying to do. But first I think you need to understand pointers better.

Comment: I admit I have to review pointer from scratch, but for now I managed to translate my pointer to char and then used the QByteArray::toBase64 and pass them to my xml using CDATA .. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the following discussion http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/27402-Save-binary-data-into-XML-file